# Sum of two really big numbers

Tags: c#

My task is to add a very big number to another and print the result.
Here is my implementation, it should give 1000 as output but it writes 0000.

How it should work: 
if the two number has equal length:
just /10 for the digit %10 for the remainder. If the length of the result is bigger than the original add the last remainder to the last element of the output array.

if the two number has different length:
sum the intersection part and add the remainder (in temp) to the relative complementl.

What is wrong?

```
static int[] SumOfBigNumbers(int[] firstNumber, int[] secondNumber)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int maxLength = (Math.Max(firstNumber.Length, secondNumber.Length));
    int minLength = (Math.Min(firstNumber.Length, secondNumber.Length));
    int[] output = new int[maxLength + 1];

    //sum of equal part
    for (int counter = 0; counter < minLength; counter++)
    {
        output[counter] = (firstNumber[counter] + secondNumber[counter] + temp) % 10;
        temp = (firstNumber[counter] + secondNumber[counter] + temp) / 10;
    }
    //exceptions add the temp to the bigger array
    if (temp!=0)
    {
        //if first array is bigger than the second
        if (firstNumber.Length > secondNumber.Length)
        {
            for (int i = minLength; i < maxLength + 1; i++)
            {
                output[i] = (firstNumber[i] + temp) % 10;
                temp = (firstNumber[i] + temp) / 10;
            }
        }
        //if second array is bigger than the first
        else if (firstNumber.Length < secondNumber.Length)
        {
            for (int i = minLength; i < maxLength + 1; i++)
            {
                output[i] = (secondNumber[i] + temp) % 10;
                temp = (secondNumber[i] + temp) / 10;
            }
        }
        //if two number has equal length but there is temp left
        else
        {
            output[maxLength] = temp;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
static void Main()
{
    int[] firstArray = new int[3] { 0, 0, 5 };
    int[] secondArray = new int[3] { 0, 0,5 };
    int[] output = SumOfBigNumbers(firstArray, secondArray);
    foreach (var i in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: better if I copy the task: Write a method that calculates the sum of two very long positive integer numbers. The numbers are represented as array digits and the last digit (the ones) is stored in the array at index 0. Make the method work for all numbers with length up to 10,000 digits.

Comment: might [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking far

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't understand why `{0,0,5}+{0,0,5}` should result in `{1,0,0,0}`. If it where `{5,0,0}+{5,0,0}` it'd make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the task. I read it as 0th element (ones) 0, 1th (tens) element 0, 2th element (hundreds) and so on. With this logic the output shouls be 0001 what can be reversed later.

Comment: @Filburt The higher the index, the more-significant the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine but you have a small bug where you display the `output` array.

You do a `foreach (var i in output) {`, but you use the `i` as an index, which it isn't. It is already the actual value. Just write the `i` to the console.

```
foreach (var i in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

// Output:
// 0
// 0
// 0
// 1
```

Or use a `for` loop to go through the array by index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
}

// Output:
// 0
// 0
// 0
// 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Now I understand what caused the error. I thought foreach works as any other loop like the simple for().

Answer (score 3):

While BigInteger is a better way to handle big numbers, I think your bug is in while printing the output. try this:

```
foreach (var i in output)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

also this will print `0001`, better reverse it while printing

Comment: Fair point about reversed order. About the code you wrote isn't it the same like I have at the bottom?

Comment: in your question you are trying to output the **i**th element of the output (output[i]) and **i** is actually the number itself not the index, try to change one of **5** in the array to **4** and you'll see index out of bounds exception